# Is there a pcntl_exec for web page

Tags: php

I wrote a lengthy php program, that spits out useful information, and at the end a signal showing it was a success or not. 
After displaying that, the program should restart with the next parameter.

Currently I add the next part within a loop. This, however, causes sooner or later a `PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size .. exhausted.`

A loop takes 5 seconds and if it is success it takes 4 seconds more.
There are now possible 370 iterations for loops.

I found

> pcntl_exec — Executes specified program in current process space

However, that is only for the command line php execution.

Is there something I can do on a web site?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full complete error message you get. Also include the source code you have to your question.

Comment: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/html/xxxphp/my.php on line 921" while reading upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: myserver.info, request: "GET /xxx.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "myhost.info"

Comment: Your script is using about 54MB memory. Depending on script you should release resources you don't need anymore to free up memory. There is no reason to hold that much memory in your PHP script.

Comment: That was not the question!!! The subject says: "Is there a pcntl_exec for web page". The memory is used up, because it tries to loop 370 times. I want to split it up into 370 calls for each one loop.

Comment: You can use `exec()` or other related functions to call any programs. But depending on what you want to do using, program execution isn't the correct way in this situation. Maybe you don't need to call external programs to split up the work and bypass the memory problem at all, instead you might be able to fix the memory problem itself.  Your question sounds like a "XY problem", maybe rephrase the question. You might want to add your source code to your question to describe your problem better, we might even tell you where the memory problem is.

Comment: Progman, thanks. It seems I could not deliver the question to you in a way you would understand. I thought the subject line is clear enough. I apologize.